# Force compile error in G++ for undeclared functions

Tags: c++, g++

I've installed GCC 4.8 using [this method](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/38222/how-do-i-install-gcc-via-homebrew/86588#86588) on my Mac. Everything works fine except that for certain functions like `scanf` and `printf`, the program compiles fine without any error/warning even when I did not include their respective libraries like `cstdio`. Is there any way that I can do to for GCC (more specifically G++, as I am dealing with C++ programs) to throw an error when such code is being fed? The following code compiles fine on my machine:

```
#include <iostream> 
//Notice I did not include cstdio but my program uses printf later on
int main()
{
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I was given the suggestion to use `-Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Werror` or `-Wall -Werror`, but they don't work.

Comment: The problem is that you don't have an implicit function declaration, but that `<iostream>` is importing the `printf` function declaration.

Comment: @juanchopanza No, the **real** problem is that OP asked a misleading question, and he is treating `C/C++` as one language.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yeah, I was suspecting something like this. Is there a way to force GCC not to do that? 'cause usually I will share my code with other people and they can't compile it.

Comment: The `<iostream>` header might include `<cstdio>` or `<stdio.h>` for you; in C++, that is allowed.  You aren't allowed to call an undeclared function in C++, so `printf()` must have been declared.

Comment: @H2CO3 nope. The problem is what I said :-)

Comment: @juanchopanza Let's agree on that there are two serious errors :)

Answer (score 2):

`-Wimplicit-function-declaration -Werror` works for me. There must be some other problems as well.

```
h2co3-macbook:~ h2co3$ cat baz.c
#ifndef BAILZ_OUT
#include <stdio.h>
#endif

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    return 0;
}
h2co3-macbook:~ h2co3$ gcc -o baz baz.c -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Werror
h2co3-macbook:~ h2co3$ echo $?
0
h2co3-macbook:~ h2co3$ gcc -o baz baz.c -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Werror -DBAILZ_OUT
cc1: warnings being treated as errors
baz.c: In function ‘main’:
baz.c:7: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘printf’
baz.c:7: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’
h2co3-macbook:~ h2co3$ echo $?
1
h2co3-macbook:~ h2co3$
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me: `cc1plus: warning: command line option '-Wimplicit-function-declaration' is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]`

Comment: It depends what you mean by "works". It doesn't "work" for me. Note OP is including `<iostream>`, which, on my gcc 4.8 snapshot, seems to include the `printf` declaration.

Comment: Simply -Wall should warn you everything, and It gives me the warning for the printf.

Comment: @RobertBean I don't want `-Wall -Werror` because there are false positives, and I'd really like to be able to compile my code.

Comment: `-Werror=implicit-function-declaration` activates only this warning as an error.  `-Werror=missing-prototypes` might help; `-Werror=strict-prototypes` too.  But all for C, not for C++.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Right. (But again, why would anyone want to compile C code with a C++ compiler? This is just pointless, isn't it?)

Comment: A trifle pointless...yes...we have to do the best we can with what the questioners ask.  C J Date sometimes invokes the 'Principle of Incoherence': it is difficult to criticize coherently that which is inherently incoherent.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Wow, I didn't know about that. But at least now I don't have to feel bad.

Comment: @H2CO3 For me, the most common case of "compiler C with a C+ compiler" would be on Windows with MSVC. The MSVC C compiler sucks balls like nobody's bushiness. So the next best thing is to use the C++ compiler.

Comment: @Mysticial (feels stupid for not knowing there was a MSVC C compiler) - so that's the real reason! I see...

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get no diagnostic is that `<iostream>` is including the declaration of `printf`, which it seems to do with the `c++0x` or `c++11` flags.

This compiles on a gcc 4.8 snapshot with the following command line:

> g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors -std=c++0x

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

If you comment out the `<iostream>` include, or remove the C++11 compilation flags, you get an error.

> impl_decl.cpp: In function 'int main()':
>
> impl_decl.cpp:5:28: error: 'printf' was not declared in this scope

Answer (score 0):

From the `Annex C/Compatibility` of the C++ standard from 2003:

**C.1 C++ and ISO C:**

> C.1.3 Clause 5: expressions [diff.expr]
>   5.2.2
>   Change: Implicit declaration of functions is not allowed
>   Rationale: The type-safe nature of C++.

That means that implicit declarations must cause a compilation error in C++.

I'm guessing you're compiling not C++ files, but C files and you're doing that in some pre-C99 mode, which is the default in gcc. The C standard from 1999 disallows implicit declarations as well.

You may want to pass to gcc a combination of these options: `-std=c99 -Werror`.

Comment: The sample code almost has to be C++; the `#include <iostream>` is not a standard C header, at any rate.  The question is confusing and/or confused.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It's not uncommon for questions to not have the actual code in them.